# How to use a different controltemplate on certain ListBox items?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, controltemplate

I have a `ListBox`where I've styled the items using the following XAML style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="120px" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="MenuButtonBorder" Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Path x:Name="MenuButtonIcon" Data="{Binding IconPathString}" Margin="0,0,0,20"
                            StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" 
                            Fill="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MenuButtonLabel" Text="{Binding Label}" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource Title1FontSize}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="MenuButtonBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="MenuButtonLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="MenuButtonIcon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="MenuButtonIcon" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `ListBox` `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` property in the viewmodel.  In one of the items, identified by the `MenuButtonLabel` value, I want to have a different template, where I've added a couple of controls.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DataTemplateSelector. Specify it as the ItemTemplateSelector for you ListBox

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}" />
```

**DataTemplateSelector**

```
class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // TODO: cast item to your viewmodel
        // return template based on the Label property;
    }
}
```

Note: You can create properties on the DataTemplateSelector for the different DataTemplates, or you can get the template from the container

```
FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
return element.FindResource("mycoolTemplate") as DataTemplate;
```